# The date command appears to convert timezones the wrong way?

Tags: bash, date, timezone

I'm working on a script where I need to convert the current time, in UTC to something else:

```
fmt="%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S"
tzone=America/Detroit
nowinutc=$(TZ=UTC date +"$fmt");echo $nowinutc
nowintz=$(date -d "TZ=\"$tzone\" $nowinutc" +"$fmt");echo $nowintz
yestintz=$(date -d "$nowintz - 1 day" +"$fmt");echo $yestintz
```

I know `America/Detroit` is 5 hours behind UTC, so `08:00:00` should become `03:00:00`, but:

```
$ fmt="%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S"
$ tzone=America/Detroit
$ nowinutc=$(TZ=UTC date +"$fmt");echo $nowinutc
2022-02-11 08:49:51
$ nowintz=$(date -d "TZ=\"$tzone\" $nowinutc" +"$fmt");echo $nowintz
2022-02-11 13:49:51
$ yestintz=$(date -d "$nowintz - 1 day" +"$fmt");echo $yestintz
2022-02-12 14:49:51
```

It's probably not the `date` command that gets it wrong, but what am I doing wrong here? It looks like everything works the opposite way of expected. Not only does the timezone conversion **add** 5 hours, but subtracting 1 day adds 25 hours - what is going on here?

Comment: `TZ=UTC date ...` means that you want the date in `UTC` timezone. `date -d 'TZ="America/Detroit" ...' ...` means that your input is in `America/Detroit` timezone. So the problem is that `2022-02-11 08:49:51` was `UTC` but you specified that it was `America/Detroit` in the `date` command

Comment: @Fravadona Oh! That makes sense, in a twisted sort of way :-)

Answer (score 1):

> so 08:00:00 should become 03:00:00

Then the input is in UTC and you are in Detroit.

```
TZ=America/Detroit date -d "08:00:00 UTC" +%H:%M:%S
TZ=America/Detroit date -d "TZ=\"UTC\" 08:00:00" +%H:%M:%S
TZ=America/Detroit date -d "08:00:00+00:00" +%H:%M:%S
```

From `man date` examples:

```
   Show the time on the west coast of the US (use tzselect(1) to find TZ)

          $ TZ='America/Los_Angeles' date

   Show the local time for 9AM next Friday on the west coast of the US

          $ date --date='TZ="America/Los_Angeles" 09:00 next Fri'
```